# Maximized programs extend to my other monitor by a pixel

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors

Whenever I maximize the windows of some programs, they extend to my second monitor (positioned to the right of my first) by a pixel of width (so I see a line of 1 pixel wide, and 1080 pixels tall on the very left side of my second monitor). This bothers me since there's a visible white line on the left of my second monitor.

Even if the program itself has a dark theme, sometimes this "line" on the second monitor becomes white. Probably some issues with how windows renders the program window.

The programs I've noticed this with are the following:

- Spotify
- Visual Studio Code

How do I fix this?

Comment: Do you have mixed DPI?

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution would be to move the picture of your screen via the setup menu of your monitor until it fits to your liking.

Comment: Do you mean move the window around and put it back to maximized mode? It doesn't fix the problem

Comment: You have a setting within your monitor menu, which allows you to move the whole picture within your screen, to fit the screen better. (Not the software window.)

Comment: I think @eQuinox means on your monitor, using the menu keys, is there an option to adjust where the image sits on the panel.

Comment: @spikey_richie yes, just fixed my comment.

Comment: @eQuinox nope, I don't have an option for that on my monitor menu

Answer (score 0):

I see this from time to time on a variety of Dell monitors we've deployed. The solution in almost every case is to root around in the monitor's OSD/menu system to find and select the Factory Reset option.